# An inequality involving the Laplacian and the norm of the gradient

Tags: functions, inequality, harmonic-functions, laplacian, functional-inequalities

For any given probability density function $p$ (with finite second moments) on $\mathbb{R}^d$ I want to show that the following integral is bigger than $\textit{(or equal to)}$ zero

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Big(\Delta\Psi(x)-\|\nabla \Psi(x)\|^2\Big) p(x)dx. $$

Obviously here I need to impose some assumptions on the function $\Psi$.

Since this needs to hold for any probability density $p$, I think the easiest thing to ask is :

Are there any conditions I can impose on a function $\Psi :\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ \Delta\Psi(x)-\|\nabla \Psi(x)\|^2 \geq 0, ~~\text{for}~a.e~x\in\mathbb{R}^d. $$

Comment: Please review the post [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|129.3530), then use a suggestion or two or three, and come back to edit and improve your post.

Comment: @amWhy is this not good enough ?

Comment: Thanks you for improving the question; I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @amWhy yep thats why I edited it? I asking is this not good enough $\textit{now}$?

Comment: I think it is fine.  I misunderstood; I saw your comment before seeing your edit.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: That condition is not sufficient for the integral being positive: think about the case when $\Psi$ is a constant. Where is this problem from?

Comment: @banana sorry I should of said $\geq 0$

Comment: The last line you show is already a condition. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

(Let me work in $d=1$) If you truly want our integral to be "bigger than zero", *i.e.* strictly positive, then your condition isn't enough for that. What *would* work would be something like $\partial_{xx}\psi-(\partial_x \psi)^2 \ge \gamma$ for all $x$, for some $\gamma >0$. You can notice that this last condition is equivalent to $-\partial_{xx}(e^{-\psi})\ge e^{-\psi}\gamma$ as a side note.

Comment: Hi Zach thats very interesting thank you for your answer. I should of been more clear I wanted to show that the integral is bigger than (or equal to) zero. How would the condition you gave change in this case?

Comment: In that case, $\partial_{xx}\psi-(\partial_x \psi)^2\ge 0$ suffices. This is in and of itself a condition on $\psi$. Are you looking for equivalent conditions? If not, what kind of conditions are you looking for? In the same spirit as my answer, your condition is equivalent to $-\partial_{xx}(e^{-\psi})\ge 0$, i.e. convexity of $-e^{-\psi}$.